# QML cannot determine the type of the property even if it's already registered

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to use Qt for my embedded application, I'm getting this issue : Home.qml:12: Error: Unknown method return type: IHome*

There is simplified of my code :

```cpp
class IHome : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int timeLabel MEMBER localTime NOTIFY localTimeChanged)

public:
    explicit IHome(QObject* parent = nullptr);

    Q_INVOKABLE void getLocalTime();

private:
    QString localTime;

signals:
    void localTimeChanged(int localTime);

public slots:

};

class Home : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    IHome* I_Home;

    explicit Home(QObject* parent = nullptr);

    Q_INVOKABLE IHome* getInterface()
    {
        I_Home->getLocalTime();
        return I_Home; 
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    
    Home home;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    qmlRegisterType<IHome>("Home", 1, 0, "HomeInfo");
    
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("home", &home);

    engine.load(QUrl(entryPoint));

    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

and the QML part is as following :

```
import Home 1.0

Item
{
    id: root
    objectName: "homeMenu"

    property HomeInfo homeInfo: getInfo();

    function getInfo() 
    {
        return home.getInterface(); // the error occurs here
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what's going wring ? Did I forget something ? I'm new to Qt.

Comment: You say you're getting an error on line 17 of a 14-line file.  Please fix your sample.

Comment: You're right, because I removed the unnecessary code, I will fix it

Comment: Your QML is invoking a method that returns a pointer to IHome, but you haven't exposed IHope to your QML.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have. There are so many mistakes in your code, for example, on **line 7**, the constructor is not named the same as the class name, and on **line 8** of `main.qml`, `HomeInterfaceInfo` is not registered at all.

Comment: I think the problem occurs because in my original code, I used nested namespace when defining my classes ! when I removed the namespace it works as expected ! But still not convinced, does namespace can cause such issues ?